# Compiling my C program with my customized library (.h) using Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction

Hi team,

I have three files which I need to compile for testing, btw im using CentOS linux.

source_code.c
library.h
library.c

1. how do I put the library.h in the gcc library, so I can use it?
2. how do I compile the source_code.c to use that library?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic knowledge of your tools, but you can do this:

`#include "library.h"` in the include section of the library.c code (at top of the file).

`gcc source_code.c library.c` in the linux terminal will link and compile both source_code.c and library.c. This will generate an executable named "a.out" (if there were no compilation problems). You can change its name, by adding the option `-o name` to the gcc command (`gcc source_code.c library.c -o mycode` will generate an executable named "mycode").

If you really need a library that will be used by a lot of other programs, you can look for "shared libraries", but I think that you are asking for a basic thing.

Comment: there are errors because of the source code can find the header (library.h). Do you know where can place that library.h using Winscp if possible? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about Winscp, but you should have all files in the same folder, have the `#include "library.h"`in the code, and do the `gcc` from terminal in the same folder where the files are.

Comment: How can I make the .h file into the shared library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need this `library.h` while building and executable (with gcc) as you should have specified the exact location of the library in the source file. All you need to do is `gcc sourcefile1.c sourcefile2.c -o exename`